# How to use different variable or array for different Listview items in Android?

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to make an e-commerce app. When I click on the ADD "+" sign, Quantity and sub-total is calculated on the basis of price.Please assist me in re-initializing the variable for each item of `ListView`. Its working fine for first Item.

[image]

[image]

Comment: you can just make the changes in your data and then can refresh your list view.

Comment: add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        
                        Long sub_total =currentItem.getPrice();


                      
                        item_sub_total = qty*sub_total;
                        quantity.setText(String.valueOf(qty));
                        subtotal.setText(String.valueOf(item_sub_total));
                    }
                });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this. But I am not satisfied. Can anyone Improve it by using List or Array???

```
add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    String q= (String) quantity.getText();
                    Double d = Double.parseDouble(q);
                    qty=d;
                    qty++;

                    Double sub_total =currentItem.getPrice();



                    item_sub_total = qty*sub_total;
                    quantity.setText(String.valueOf(qty));
                    subtotal.setText(String.valueOf(item_sub_total));
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

create a class and declare its members accordingly. now whenever you need to add a new row create the object of that class and assign values to them.

example:

create a class named MyEntity

```
public class MyEntity {

    String entity = "";
    double price = 0.0;
    int quantity = 0;
    double subTotal = 0.0;

    public MyEntity(String entity, double price, int quantity, double subTotal) {
        this.entity = entity;
        this.price = price;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.subTotal = subTotal;
    }
}
```

usage:

Create a List in your activity or wherever you are creating the list as

```
List<MyEntity> myEntityList = new ArrayList<>();
```

on click of add button create the object of MyEntity class like

```
add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        String q = (String) quantity.getText();
        Double d = Double.parseDouble(q);
        qty=d;
        qty++;

        Double sub_total =currentItem.getPrice();

        item_sub_total = qty*sub_total;

        MyEntity myEntity = new MyEntity("Onion", sub_total, qty, item_sub_total);

        myEntityList.add(myEntity);
    }
});
```

pass this list to your list view adapter and use accordingly

you can access the fields like
        myEntity.price
or
        myEntity.subTotal etc.